# Convert columns values to columns in spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column **hit** with schema as

```
 |-- hit: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- double_value: void (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- float_value: void (nullable = true)
```

Sample values in column hit, in a list there are values :

```
[{A,{null,2,null,null}},{B,{1,null,null,null}}]
```

I have a list of expected

```
columns =['A','B','C','D']
```

What I want is first search the list for the columns, if it is found then convert the key to a column name else null should flow.
For eg. search for A,B,C,D in the column **hit** and the final output should be :

```
**A B C D**                                                                            
2 1 null null
```

I have tried using explode and also writing custom functions but it is still not working.

Comment: The `value` struct has two void fields? But your shown data has 4, two being an int, not void?

Comment: which value do you need: double_value or  float_value?

Comment: Sorry I think I typed it incorrectly. It has 2 values double_value and a float_value. I need the value which is not null. At a point there will be a single not null value.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of task if the list of columns is known in advance, can be easily done in spark-sql using explode and conditional aggregation.

If key == 'A' then take value, else null + aggregate using max() as column A, repeat for all columns:

```
select 
      hit, 
      max(case when hit_element.key='A' 
                  then hit_element.value.double_value
                       --or you need float_value, NVL()+MVL()
               else null
           end) as A,
      max(case when hit_element.key='B' 
                  then hit_element.value.double_value
                       --or you need float_value, or NVL()+MVL()
               else null
           end) as B,
           max(case when hit_element.key='C' 
                  then hit_element.value.double_value
                       --or you need float_value, or NVL()+MVL()
               else null
           end) as C,
                 max(case when hit_element.key='D' 
                  then hit_element.value.double_value
                       --or you need float_value, or NVL()+MVL()
               else null
           end) as D
 from your_data d
      lateral view outer explode(d.hit) e as hit_element
 group by hit --if you have some key on the same level, better use it for groupby
```

It is not cleas which value do you need double_value or float_value or both combined, but you can easily adjust the code I provided and calculate whatever necessary instead of `hit_element.value.double_value`

Comment: @Sk2415 something like this should work according to your last comment `coalesce(hit_element.value.double_value, hit_element.value.float_value)`